# Double value in Dictionary

Tags: c#, data-dictionary

I have this code to get two double from jSon:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = this.GetDicFromInput();
Decimal tmpLat = (Decimal)dict["lat"];
Decimal tmpLon = (Decimal)dict["lon"];
```

This is `GetDicFromInput`:

```
private Dictionary<string, object> GetDicFromInput()
{
    string input = null;

    input = "{\"lon\":34.806109,\"lat\":31.9599733}";

    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer() { MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue };
    Dictionary<string, object> dict = (Dictionary<string, object>)json.DeserializeObject(input);

    return dict;
}
```

And when I run it I get:

```
 [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   BabySitter.Search.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in \\psf\home\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\BabySitter\BabySitter\Search.aspx.cs:28
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

This is the fail line:

```
Decimal tmpLat = (Decimal)dict["lat"];
```

Comment: Is DeserializeObject returning null?

Comment: no, it return a dictonary with the two objects

Comment: Which line is line 28?

Comment: `Dictionary<string, object> dict = (Dictionary<string, object>)json.DeserializeObject(input);` - Aren't you missing the `new` keyword here?

Comment: And it return Dictionary without the new key

Comment: Are you using .Net 4.0? I've just copy pasted your code to a brand new console application and it works.

Comment: Yes i use .net 4, the weired issue is that when i run it in the debug mode it run good but when i run the same code on my iis server it fail

Comment: I've came accross a similar problem that explains that you need to set your json's max length, but in your case you've already done that. So that's weird. Try printing out some debug info. For example, before the `Decimal tmpLat = (Decimal)dict["lat"];` line, try printing how many items does the dictionary hold (and if not zero then what are they), and we'll continue from there...

Comment: Thanks for the help, i make a clean on the project and remove it from the iis and upload again and it work perfectly. thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the generic function to return the exact object type you are creating.

```
public T Deserialize<T>(string input)
```

In this case,

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = json.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>(input);
```